# Block internet access before firewall starts at boot

Tags: internet, mobile-network, 3g, firewall, init.d

I have an old Android phone with Ice Cream Sandwich and DroidWall as a firewall, which makes sure that apps can't use the 3G unless I enable it for that app. DroidWall starts on boot but there is a very brief time before it starts when any app can use the internet.

What I would like to do is stop all incoming and outgoing internet access until DroidWall automatically runs on boot to put the firewall rules in place. DroidWall allows running a script when it starts so conceivably I could undo the block-everything rules when it starts. The phone is rooted but doesn't have a `/etc/init.d/`.

Basically I want to make sure there is not even a second that traffic can get out before the firewall. 3G is expensive but I need it so I can't turn it off.

Comment: Would it suffice if an automation app disables the mobile data during shutdown and enables it after n seconds of boot (assuming Droidwall would be started by than)?

Comment: @Firelord Is there a flag I can set to make sure it always starts with mobile data disabled, and do you know how I can enable it after the script runs?

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246459/how-to-prevent-network-connectivity-after-a-phone-restart-before-the-netguard-fi

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed, DroidWall is no more maintained, rooting techniques have to be changed with Android 5 and 6 releases; particularly SELinux has to be taken care of, and there is always `init.d` support available with Magisk. But the question still stands valid.

Android depends on Linux kernel's builtin firewall which can be controlled with `iptables`. Default policy is `ACCEPT` which can be set to `DROP` on boot, unless all rules are loaded. This can be done with a simple `init.d` script or directly from Android's `init` services:

```
# /system/etc/init/firewall_policy.rc

on post-fs-data
    exec u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

After boot, set policy back to `ACCEPT`. AFWall+ does this automatically.